# Apply percentage formatting to a ztable

Tags: r

I have a ztable and this is my code

```
library(titanic)
library(ztable)
library(dplyr)

ztable(xtabs(Freq ~ Class + Age, data = data.frame(Titanic))) %>% 
makeHeatmap(palette="Blues")
```

I'd like to make the numbers into percents. I don't want to convert them to percent of totals.

I want to just add percent formatting to each of the numbers. So the first row would be: 6%, 319%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mytable <- xtabs(Freq ~ Class + Age, data = data.frame(Titanic))

formatted_table <- as.data.frame(matrix(
  sprintf("%.0f%%", mytable),
  nrow(mytable),
  dimnames = dimnames(mytable)
))

ztable(formatted_table)
```

[image]

This doesn't seem to work with `makeHeatmap()`, though, which is probably because it adds non-numeric characters to the table).